# Handle first_open in app (not in Google Analytics)

Tags: android, flutter, firebase

I want to handle `first_open` Firebase event in my Android app (in addition to handling it in GA4). That is my app should receive a notification when the user opens it first time.

The app is made with Flutter.

1. How to implement it?
2. Will it be difficult for a hacker to forge my backend into thinking that `first_open` happened?